# How to use SingleChildScrollView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub

this is my code... it says error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n92e9.png)

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    weightIndicator(
                      0,
                      '0,2 kg',
                    ),
                    weightIndicator(
                      0,
                      '0,4 kg',
                    ),
                    weightIndicator(
                      0,
                      '0,6 kg',
                    ),
                    weightIndicator(
                      0,
                      '0,8 kg',
                    ),
                    weightIndicator(
                      0,
                      '1,0 kg',
                    ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

how to fix the error?

Comment: *how to fix the error?* - what error?  Might you please [edit] your post to share the problem you are having, and where you are struck?  See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this Row with SingleChildScrollView , you can either use Wrap or use the ListView with the axisDirection as Axis.horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Use this property inside "SingleChildScrollView",

```
 -scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
```